# Dividing a string into substring in JAVA

Tags: java, substring

As per my project I need to devide a string into two parts.

below is the example:

```
String searchFilter = "(first=sam*)(last=joy*)";
```

Where `searchFilter` is a string.
I want to split above string to two parts

`first=sam*` and `last=joy*`
so that i can again split this variables into `first,sam*,last` and `joy*` as per my requirement.

I dont have much hands on experience in java. Can anyone help me to achieve this one. It will be very helpfull.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most flexible way is probably to do it with regular expressions:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a regular expression pattern
        Pattern spec = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)=(.*?)\\)");

        // Get a matcher for the searchFilter
        String searchFilter = "(first=sam*)(last=joy*)";
        Matcher m = spec.matcher(searchFilter);

        // While a "abc=xyz" pattern can be found...
        while (m.find())
            // ...print "abc" equals "xyz"
            System.out.println("\""+m.group(1)+"\" equals \""+m.group(2)+"\"");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
"first" equals "sam*"
"last" equals "joy*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `String.split(..)` and `String.substring(..)`, using them you should be able to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using `split` or `substring` or using `StringTokenizer`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it in a lot of different ways, it depends on you.
Using regexp or what else look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html.

Anyway I suggest:

```
int separatorIndex = searchFilter.indexOf(")(");
String filterFirst = searchFilter.substring(1,separatorIndex);
String filterLast = searchFilter.substring(separatorIndex+1,searchFilter.length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a small code that will solve ur problem

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(searchFilter, "(||)||=");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
        }
```

It will give the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

This (untested snippet) could do it:

```
 String[] properties = searchFilter.replaceAll("(", "").split("\)");
 for (String property:properties) {
   if (!property.equals("")) {
      String[] parts = property.split("=");
      // some method to store the filter properties
      storeKeyValue(parts[0], parts[1]); 
   }
 }
```

The idea behind: First we get rid of the brackets, replacing the opening brackets and using the closing brackets as a split point for the filter properties. The resulting array includes the String `{"first=sam*","last=joy*",""}` (the empty String is a guess - can't test it here). Then for each property we split again on "=" to get the key/value pairs.

Comment: All JVM's I know of evaluate `property != ""` to false (as posted in the snippet above).

Comment: As I said - untested - I was unsure if the first split adds an empty String to the array, because the String ends with a ")". If this is not the case, the test you mentioned is obsolete.

Comment: what I meant was that it **always** returns false (on all modern JVM's I'm familiar with). You'll want to use `equals(...)` instead.

Comment: make that a double espresso! :)